# Definite Integral Arising from a Double Integral

Tags: integration, special-functions

I gave an integral to a student.  She reported back to me that she could not do it.  I've tried a couple of approaches and have failed.  I imagine it is fairly easy.  It's a double integral.  And, no matter, which variable you do first, you end up with an integral like:
$$
\int_1^2 \frac{1}{3x}e^{x^5}\,dx.
$$
Any help would be appreciated.  In case I have messed up the initial integrations, the original integral was:
$$
\int_1^2\int_1^3 x^4y^2e^{x^5y^3}\,dy\,dx.
$$

Comment: If only the original integrand was $x^4y^2e^{x^5+y^3}$...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This integral pertains to the [exponential integral function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_integral), $\text{Ei}(z)$, so you weren't going to get it done by hand.

*Mathematica* confirms:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Just to make sure, let's check the double integral as well:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

---

PS Note the particular definition *Mathematica* employs here for $\text{Ei}(z)$:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Thanks.  If you'll believe it, I grabbed the integral from an ordinary undergraduate calculus book.

Comment: Yeah, probably just a typo somewhere...

Answer (score 0):

FWIW, here's how $\mathrm{Ei}$ shows up:

$$\int\frac{\exp\,t^5}{t}\mathrm dt=\frac15\int\frac{5t^4 \exp\,t^5}{t^5}\mathrm dt=\frac15\int\frac{\exp\,u}{u}\mathrm du$$

where the simple substitution $u=t^5$ was made. Since $\mathrm{Ei}$ is defined as the integral of $\frac{\exp\,u}{u}$, that's how it turns up.